# Float left doesnt work

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to put an html code in my wordpress widget, to show something in top of my page, here's the code, but the last float which is the Phone numbers that i wanna put in the left of the button that are already in the right, its just not working well and it will stay right beside the buttons, i appreciate if you can help me out what is wrong and why.

thank you.

```css
section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

section li {
  float: right;
  border-right: 5px solid;
  border-color: white;
}

section li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

section li p {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section .button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #955251;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 45px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

section .button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

section .button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

section .ultopnav a:link:active,
a:visited:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: auto;
}

section .ultopnav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

section .ultopnav a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.ultopnav .floatleft {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul class="ultopnav">
    <li><button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span><a 
href="http://www.chistagostar.com">خانه </a></span></button></li>

    <li><button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span><a 
href="http://www.shop.chistagostar.com">صفحه اول فروشگاه </a></span>
</button></li>

    <li>
      <p class="floatleft" style="float: left;">تلفن: 77863967 - 021 | فکس: 77267261 - 021</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to float the `<p>` left within the `<li>` when you should actually float the `<li>` left, like so:

```css
section ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
}

section li {
float: right;
border-right:5px solid;
border-color: white;
}

section li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}


section li p {
display: block;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

section .button {
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #955251;
border: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
font-size: 16px;
width: 120px;
height: 45px;
transition: all 0.5s;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 5px;
align-items: center;
}

section .button span {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transition: 0.5s;
}

section .button span:after {
content: '\00bb';
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
right: -20px;
transition: 0.5s;
}

section .ultopnav a:link:active, a:visited:active { 
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: auto;
}


section .ultopnav a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

section .ultopnav a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
.ultopnav .floatleft {
color: black;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<section>
  <ul class="ultopnav">
    <li>
      <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle; align: right">
        <span><a 
href="http://www.chistagostar.com">خانه </a></span>
      </button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <span><a 
href="http://www.shop.chistagostar.com">صفحه اول فروشگاه </a></span>
      </button>
    </li>

    <li style="float: left;">
      <p class="floatleft">تلفن: 77863967 - 021 | فکس: 77267261 - 021</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

issue is that you use `float:left` for `<p` tag.instead you need to use it for `<li>` tag.
please try this code..

```css
section ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
}

section li {
float: right;
border-right:5px solid;
border-color: white;
}

section li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}


section li p {
display: block;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

section .button {
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #955251;
border: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
font-size: 16px;
width: 120px;
height: 45px;
transition: all 0.5s;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 5px;
align-items: center;
}

section .button span {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transition: 0.5s;
}

section .button span:after {
content: '\00bb';
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
right: -20px;
transition: 0.5s;
}

section .ultopnav a:link:active, a:visited:active { 
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: auto;
}


section .ultopnav a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

section .ultopnav a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
.ultopnav .floatleft {
color: black;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<section><ul class="ultopnav">
<li><button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span><a 
href="http://www.chistagostar.com">خانه </a></span></button></li>

<li><button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span><a 
href="http://www.shop.chistagostar.com">صفحه اول فروشگاه </a></span>
</button></li>

<li style="float: left;"><p class="floatleft">تلفن: 77863967 - 021 | فکس: 77267261 - 021</p></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
section li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
    float: left;
}
```